# preg_replace all "(.+)" but equal "=" in a ini file line

Tags: php, regex

I can’t find the exact answer for my question, which is:

How to create a `preg_replace` regex that replace the *source* by:

- $key => `url_rewriter.tags`,
- $val => `"a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset= "`

Soucre: `url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset = "`

I wrote this, but something is going wrong:

```
$v = 'url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset = "';
$key = preg_replace('/^(.+[^=])[\\s]*=[\\s]*(.*)$/', '$1', $v);
$val = preg_replace('/^(.+[^=])[\\s]*=[\\s]*(.*)$/', '$2', $v);
```

It returns:

- $key => `url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset`
- $val => `"`

What am I missing ?

Comment: Your regex does not acutally look for the enclosing `"` quotes, and `.+` is greedy.

Comment: What is the output you want? to remove the tag

Comment: @mario yep, i know, but i ask him to stop on the `=` with the `[^=]` no ? why it doesn't stop ? :(

Comment: You're only matching `[^=]` **after** `.+` has already consumed *anything, and as much as possible of that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$v = 'url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset = "';

$key = preg_replace('/^([^\s=]*)\s*=\s*(.*)$/', '$1', $v);
$val = preg_replace('/^([^\s=]*)\s*=\s*(.*)$/', '$2', $v);
```

http://ideone.com/ibtW9h

Or better yet:

```
if (preg_match('/^([^\s=]*)\s*=\s*(.*)$/', $v, $match))
    list(, $key, $val) = $match;
else
    die('Error. Invalid source.');
```

Comment: i tested the preg_match method, this does not match ... idk why :/  the var_dump returns : `int(0)` and `array(0) { }` **But a big thanks for this help :)**